# Command Prompt not separating responses... running them on one continuous line

Tags: windows, cmd, command

Recently my Windows 11 PC is displaying Command Prompt responses on one continuous line rather than separate lines.

Here' a couple of comparisons using Robocopy in a batch file:

On my old PC running Windows 10 running Robocopy from a batch file looks like this:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4046]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Robocopy>c:\robocopy\robocopy "\\NITRO1\d$\Ableton" "\\media01\4TB\DashCam\ToyotaSienna2020" /e /r:3 /w:3 /xo /v**


ROBOCOPY v 1.54  :  Robust File Copy for Windows NT  :  by kevina@microsoft.com

  Started : Wed Feb 21 12:27:41 2024

   Source : \\NITRO1\d$\Ableton\
     Dest : \\media01\4TB\DashCam\ToyotaSienna2020\
    Files : *.*
  Options : *.* /S /E /V /XO /R:3 /W:3

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

                       3  \\NITRO1\d$\Ableton\
*EXTRA Dir            -1  \\media01\4TB\DashCam\ToyotaSienna2020\DashcamMichael2023-05-20\
*EXTRA Dir            -1  \\media01\4TB\DashCam\ToyotaSienna2020\DashcamMichael2023-10-29\
*EXTRA Dir            -1  \\media01\4TB\DashCam\ToyotaSienna2020\DashcamMichael2024-01-18\
  *EXTRA File              721875000  VID_20210110_161015.AVI
  *EXTRA File              721875000  VID_20210110_161515.AVI
  *EXTRA File              721875000  VID_20210110_162015.AVI
  *EXTRA File              962253824  VID_20210110_162356.AVI
  *EXTRA File              750672896  VID_20210110_162857.AVI
  *EXTRA File              721875000  VID_20210110_163357.AVI
  *EXTRA File              721875000  VID_20210110_163715.AVI
  *EXTRA File              721875000  VID_20210110_164216.AVI
  *EXTRA File              721875000  VID_20210110_164716.AVI
  *EXTRA File              433125000  VID_20220410_183023.AVI
    New File                 6310247  From_Start_to_Finish_in_Live_11_-_Free_Samples.zip
    New File               120068726  PML_-_Aperitivo_-_Taster_Sample_Pack_(ProductionMusicLive.com).zip
```

But on my newer PC responses are all wrapped on the same line wrapping to the next line.  Any ideas what's causing this?

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.2538]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\mcook>cd \robocopy

C:\Robocopy>4tb

C:\Robocopy>REM - ophcrack to 4TB

C:\Robocopy>c:\robocopy\robocopy "H:\Incomplete" "\\media01\4tb\Ophtcrack" /s /r:3 /w:3 /xo /v
/move
H:\Incomplete\\\media01\4tb\Ophtcrack\*.*
            *.* /V /S /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /MOVE /XO /R:3 /W:3 H:\Incomplete\\\media01\4tb\Ophtc
rack\ophcrack-3.8.0-bin\\\media01\4tb\Ophtcrack\ophcrack_xp_tables\ophcrack_pro_tables.torrentx
p_free_fast.md5xp_free_fast.sfvH:\Incomplete\ophcrack_pro_tables\b2sum.txtDISCLAIMER.txtmd5sum.
txtsha1sum.txtH:\Incomplete\ophcrack_pro_tables\vista_eight\table0.bintable0.indextable0.startt
able1.bintable1.indextable1.start
```

**CLARIFICATION:**  I've saved various versions of the Robocopy.exe to my fully updated Windows 11 pc and have noticed that the "line wrapping" behavior  I'm experiencing is present on all newer versions of Robocopy.  I expect it's some kind of parameter that I'm failing to specify in the batch file I'm executing called "4tb".

The command in the batch file is basically the following:
"C:\Robocopy>c:\robocopy\robocopy "H:\Incomplete" "\media01\4tb\Ophtcrack" /s /r:3 /w:3 /xo /v
/move"

Running the same batch file but switching the Robocopy versions by erenaming the Robocopy.exe file is what produces the varying outputs.

Comment: It's hard for us to say, especially when your Windows 11 OS is not up to date, and the only thing you've shown us is that your twenty-eight year old version of `Robocopy`, written for Windows NT4, is producing results in a different format to the built-in Windows 11 OS version. The rest of the output in your Command Prompt is using line breaks exactly consistent with standard behavior. _I should also mention that as we have not been told what the command `4tb` is, or what it does, how are we supposed determine whether that could have triggered your problem_.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out!  When I started using Robocopy it was a part of the NT Resource Kit.  I eventually updated to the 2003 resource kit but never realized it was included in Windows.  My "behavior" was to copy the exe into a local folder "eg. C:\Robocopy" and create various batch files to run it from there.  Running the newer versions from this location is what causes Robocopy to supress the full exe output to the command window.

So, I edited my batch files to simply call the Robocopy from the "system location" (eg... not "c:\robocopy\robocopy [source] [destination] /varibles"   but simply "robocopy [source] [destination] /varibles" and the full output is restored to the command window.

The clue that gave it away was when I ran a batch file from a pc that did not have the correct source and destination paths I was returned **"The resource loader cache doesn't have loaded MUI entry."**  Investigation reveals that Robocopy has some location-specific dependencies to fully operate.

Thanks all for your help!